# Binance API Error Code 1102, Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance

I'm trying to use Binance API to do the trade on a linux server.

I don't know what is wrong with my code.

I did send timestamp but still got an error.

(I know that I can use ccxt, but want to know why this error happened)

I am getting this error:

```
{
  code: -1102,
  msg: "Mandatory parameter 'timestamp' was not sent, was empty/null, or malformed."
}
```

[API Dosc](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#10xx-general-server-or-network-issues)

below is my code, thanks

```
// settings
const setting = require('./json/binance.json');
// packages
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const apiKey = setting.apiKey;
const apiSecret = setting.secret;

// Headers
const headers = {
    'X-MBX-APIKEY': apiKey,
};

// Signature
function generateSignature(params) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(params).digest('hex');
}

function placeFuturesOrder(req) {
    const symbol = req.body.symbol;
    const side = req.body.side;
    const type = 'MARKET';
    const quantity = req.body.amount

    const baseUrl = 'https://fapi.binance.com';
    const endpoint = '/fapi/v1/order';
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    const params = `symbol=${symbol}&side=${side}&type=${type}&quantity=${quantity}&timestamp=${timestamp}`;
    const signature = generateSignature(params);

    const postData = {
        symbol,
        side,
        type,
        quantity,
        timestamp,
        signature,
    };

    return axios.post(baseUrl + endpoint, postData, { headers });
}
```

Comment: *"...or is malformed."* What you're sending is a number (milliseconds since The Epoch). Does the API expect a number, or a date/time string? (If it accepts a number, is it expecting milliseconds since The Epoch or seconds since The Epoch? [Or something else, though that seems unlikely?])

Comment: idk, but thanks for your advise.

Comment: Could it be that your Linux server time is out of sync?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to put all parameters in the url, it should work.
You could see an example from this github code snippet https://github.com/binance/binance-signature-examples/blob/master/python/futures/um_futures.py#L116